# Fitbit Stocks Data for Watch Face

Tags: stock, fitbit, watchface

I am trying to create a Fitbit watchface that displays stock data or certain stock. Does anyone know how to do this. I am just learning how to work this thing

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, clarify what you've tried to solve the problem and what difficulties you're experiencing? I also recommend to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that your questions could find the answers

Answer (score 0):

So there is not much on fit bit studio but there are a few very good tutorials that can get a beginner like me started. Here is a link. If there is something out there that somebody knows how to call on an external API to use within fit bit, please don't hesitate to post it in here. It will help me and many other noob programmers :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gISL5qa607M